# Is there a way to send private message on gaming?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, user-profile

I feel like an idiot, but I don't see any way to send a private message to someone, is this not allowed or am I a blind old man? I want to prompt someone to accept my answer since they said it fixed their problem but they didn't accept the answer.

Also, I don't know if I am supposed to even do that or if the system will remind them or whatever.

Also I'm not sure if this question is the right type of question for meta, so please don't punish me too hard if that's the case.

Comment: I suspect you're talking about [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43756/in-rusty-hearts-how-do-i-get-the-a-simple-task-mission-to-complete-the-all-i) question of mine. I know how accepting an answer works, but I'd like a more complete one. Yours helped me, so I upvoted it, but it doesn't cover some of the core bits (mainly having to join the Militia), and looks a bit unfinished ("I'll try follow up with my results"). - In any case, I usually wait a day or two before accepting an answer.

Comment: ok cool. Got it. thanks for the feedback. yeah i'd figured i'd send you a note, and if you told me that there I'd fix it up. Just was unsure about the way things work here, as I'm a noob.

Comment: So this is off-topic now, but would the proper thing in this circumstance be to go back and edit my answer to include the actual details you got from the video I posted, and make a comment about how I edited to include that? Seems to be the case, right?

Comment: Yes, you can edit your answers to flesh them out a bit. Leaving a comment isn't really necessary, though. You can note what you changed in the edit summary.

Comment: will do, and I'll delete my comment I just made ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do so through the website and no plans to make such a thing available. Sorry.

[How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Comment: thanks. I didn't see that question because I was searching for things like "message" and "messaging" and "private" and it didn't come up.

Comment: @InsidiousForce No worries.

Comment: oh and also cos it's on a totally different site. new to the whole stack thing.

Comment: @InsidiousForce Glad to see it's working out for you! Keep it up!

Answer (score 2):

Stack exchange does not support private messaging between members at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The trite response to this is "StackExchange is not Facebook".  See [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) on Meta StackOverflow (MSO) for more rationale.

If you would like to contact someone privately, your only hope is if they have some external contact information on their profile (click their name, see top-right).

Comment: I wasn't remotely trying to equate the two. I was curious about prompting someone to use the system the way it's intended, not to start up a chat session, post pictures of my lunch, or talk about the weather and my kids or my politics. Or garner "friends" even.